# R Read.table: sep when there are more than 1 occurence

Tags: r, read.table

I have a big list of the format
Variable = Value.
99% of the list is in this format. However, very few entries need to have a = within the value part. So they look like Variable = Value = something

So my read.table function throws an error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 2 elements
```

Is there a way to avoid this without having to change the original file?
This is my read table command:

```
VarNamesDescription<-read.table(paste(FilePathVariableDescription), sep="=", skip=0, header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

EDIT:
Cell with one =

```
AABB NA=HOLDING NV
```

Cell with two =

```
AA=ETX Sml = PrM013)
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see at least part of the file you're trying to read.

Comment: Please give us an example file with three lines, and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that you'll have a maximum of 3 `=`'s in a line, you can force `read.table` to allocate an extra column with `colClasses` and `fill`.

```
txt <- "a=2
b=3
c=4
d=5=6
e=7"
read.table(text=txt, sep="=", header=FALSE,
    colClasses=c("character","character","character"), # create a 3rd column
    fill=TRUE # don't fail because data for last column doesn't exist 
    )

  V1 V2 V3
1  a  2   
2  b  3   
3  c  4   
4  d  5  6
5  e  7
```

Comment: VarNamesDescription<-read.table(FilePathVariableDescription, sep="=",skip=0,colClasses=c("character", "character", "character"),header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Warning message:
In read.table(FilePathVariableDescription, sep = "=", skip = 0,  :
  cols = 2 != length(data) = 3

Comment: Got it to work with this: VarNamesDescription<-read.table(FilePathVariableDescription, sep="=",skip=0,col.names=c("a","b","c"),header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE). Thx alot!